# How to diagnose corrupt DLL's with DXDIAG and MSINFO

Tags: windows-10

I am currently talking with a software support team trying to diagnose why a program crashes on my computer. It is a Windows 10 Pro 1703 system and the software is supposed to be compatible.

They asked for the output of DXDIAG and MSINFO to help diagnose the problem. They suggested that the output files I sent suggested that "certain Windows DLL's have corrupted". They do not specify which and only advise to run my chosen anti-virus checker for a full-scan and sfc /scannow "up to three times".

My anti-virus software is just Windows Defender and finds nothing. SFC finds no errors.

My question is *how do I determine which DLL's are supposed to be corrupt using DXDIAG and MSINFO output?*

I would like to verify the claims by the software company and fix Windows if the claims are true. If they aren't, I don't want to waste a day or two repairing a Windows Installation that doesn't need fixing.

*** Corrected typo in operating system ***

*** UPDATE ***

SFC /scannow, Chkdsk c: /r/f, Windows Defender Full Scan and Offline Scan have all come back clean. Never had a single piece of malware on this installation of Windows. What can DXDIAG and MSINFO output tell me that SFC, Chkdsk and Windows Defender cannot?

*** UPDATE ***

After poking around in the output files it seems that in the MSINFO output > Software Environment > Windows Error Reporting log names a faulting application and faulting module. Is it possible to tell which has the problem, the application, the module or both?

Comment: That's a cop-out answer from your vendor. They need to provide you with an option to enable some verbose logging to diagnose.

Comment: 1706? Do you mean 1703 or 1709.  1706 isn’t a valid version of Windows 10.  Edit your question and clarify.  “SFC finds no errors.” - This means your system files are not corrupt.  Doesn’t mean a different file that’s required is not corrupt but you have zero corrupted system files

Comment: @spikey_richie That is what I first thought, however I wanted to double check before making any assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

- You can try `chkdsk C: /f /r` command on cmd tool, which `C:` is your windows installed directory, sometimes a silent Hard drive failure don't show itself until your installed program refers to corrupted files.
- You can find faulty file name by clicking "View problem details" on crash report window:

[Crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WrQ2.png)

BUT note that knowing about faulty DLL file, doesn't mean you CAN replace it by downloading.